# getting JSON string into Knockout observable multiselectlist

Tags: c#, json, knockout.js

I am trying to get my JSON string passed through the ViewBag into my knockout observable and use that to populate a multiselectlist.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but right now it is taking each individual character in the JSON string and sticking it in it's own line in the select list.

Here is my C# controller code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> salesReps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach ( var rep in salespeople.Salesperson )
        {
            salesReps.Add( rep.Code, rep.Code + " - " + rep.fullName );
        }
        //ViewBag.salespeople = salespeople.Salesperson.Select( x => x.Code ).Distinct().ToList();
        ViewBag.salespeople = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( salesReps );
```

And here is the Knockout code:

```
var cSource = function (data) {
        var self = this;

        .....
        self.salesPeople = ko.observableArray();
};

$(document).ready(function () {

        var modelData = @Html.Raw( Json.Encode( Model ) );

        mySource = new cSource(modelData);

        //var salesRepList = Html.Raw( Json.Encode( ViewBag.salespeople ) );
        var salesRepList = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.salespeople));
        console.log(salesRepList);

        mySource.salesPeople = salesRepList;
```

And here is the HTML select code:

```
<select data-bind="
options: salesPeople,
selectedOptions: chosenReps,
optionsCaption: 'Choose rep(s)'
"></select>
```

And a small snippet of what my console.log spits out:

```
{"USERNAME1":"USERNAME1 - Full Name 1","USERNAME2":"USERNAME2 - Full Name 2","USERNAME3":"USERNAME3 - Full Name 3",..... }
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the c# code to create named variables in the JSON now.  Here is my new console.log output:

```
{"username":"BOBC","fullname":"Bob Cottin"},{"username":"JIMT","fullname":"Jim Thorpe"},{"username":"LUKEP","fullname":"Luke Peppin"}, ....}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed immediately is that you seem to be overwriting your salesPeople observable with a flat value. "mySource.salesPeople = salesRepList" should probably be "mySource.salesPeople(salesRepList)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options binding is expecting an array of objects or values, but according to your console log salesPeople is a single dictionary style object. You may need to convert that to an array so the binding knows how to parse it into select options.

If you only need the value property and can disregard the "Username1", "Username2", etc then you could use a loop like this to grab the value properties of the object:

```
for (var x in salesRepList) {
    if (salesRepList.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        mySource.salesPeople.push(salesRepList[x]);
    }
}
```

If you need the more complex types then you'll have to create an array of objects, or (per your last edit) have your json pass them with standard parameter names. Then you can use knockout's optionsText binding to tell the select which property on the object to use as the display text.

Per example:3 of the [knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountry,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Here's a jsFiddle with some of that adapted to your example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/ms34Lv0v/)

Comment: I need both parts of the JSON string.  Would it help to create a JSON string with named values?

Comment: For the select list, I want the value to be "USERNAME1" and the text to be "USERNAME1 - Full Name 1".

Comment: I tried adding this loop in place of the `mySource.salesPeople(salesRepList)` and I keep getting "warning: unresponsive script" with the ability to continue, debug or stop.  I've hit continue several times and it keeps coming up.  I'm guessing infinite loop or very very long loop.

Comment: In that case you'll have to parse it to an array of objects instead of string literals, and then use knockout's value and optionsText bindings to tell it which properties on the object to use for the select. I'll update my answer with an example in a few minutes

Comment: For the infinite loop... if you haven't yet fixed the part where your code says "mySource.salesPeople = salesRepList;" then you're probably parsing from and pushing to the same array.

Comment: This got me on the right path and I got it figured out, so I marked it as the answer.  Thank you!